# Make AutoComplete in React Native android

Tags: react-native

How we can make autocomplete Input and also selectable in react native android.
I have a array of data and I want to make autocomplete with this data.
this is a array of data

```
 var array = [   
    {name: 'awesomepankaj'},    
    {name: 'akshay'},    
    {name: 'Ram'},    
    {name: 'akash'},   
    {name: 'Noname'}  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at npm package fuzzy https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy

It allows for fuzzy autocomplete like in sublime editor. I've not tested it but i guess you can use it in react-native like other npm packages

```
npm install --save fuzzy
var fuzzy = require('fuzzy');
```